# When calling facebook's api dashboard.publishActivity where does it go to?

Tags: facebook

I want to test this api(dashboard.publishActivity) - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/dashboard.publishActivity/

But I'm not sure where the messages go to. The documentation says it goes to the activity streams of user's friends. What exactly do they mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, they've removed the API. This doesn't work anymore